# Shortest path in an undirected and complete graph?

Tags: graph, shortest-path, dijkstra, quickgraph

I have a question which may be very simple but when deadline is looming the brain stops working so there goes:

I have an undirected complete graph with N nodes in it. I have a starting node and I have the distance matrix from each node to the other nodes. I want to run Dijkstra's algorithm or any other algorithm that would work  to find the shortest way of visiting all the nodes from the starting node. I want to visit each node only once.
I believe the fact that it is a complete graph where each node is connected to the others would make the problem much easier but I cannot wrap my head around coding it.
I am using C#. I have already asked another question earlier but this was at an earlier stage where I didn't know much about the problem. 
Are there any code snippets or pseudo codes available out there or if anyone could start me out I would be very thankful.

I have been looking at QuickGraph and its documentation and other online sources but I can't figure out what I need to have as parameters to run the algorithm. more precisely I don't understand the below code:

```
IVertexAndEdgeListGraph<TVertex, TEdge> graph = ...;
Func<TEdge, double> edgeCost = e => 1; // constant cost
TVertex root = ...;
// compute shortest paths
TryFunc<TVertex, TEdge> tryGetPaths = graph.ShortestPathDijkstra(edgeCost, root);
```

The above code snippet was taken from: http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Dijkstra%20Shortest%20Distance%20Example
if anybody with experience in quickgraph could explain it to me in simple terms what I need to have to make  use the below functions that would save me.

To explain what I have is I have a list of Points (x,y) from which I want to build a graph but only showing the edges of the shortest path.

link to my old post:
    [Run Dijkstra's Algorithm on a List<Point> in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058722/run-dijkstras-algorithm-on-a-listpoint-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Do you want to visit every node once or do you want the shortest path to each node? If you want to visit every node once then you should not be looking at dijkstra but rather at Travelling Salesperson algorithms.